# Issue with receiving GET from $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hey guys I am trying to receive the following

```
function sendUserfNotes() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/pcg/popups/grabnotes.php',
        data: {
            'nameNotes': notes_name.text(),
        },
        success: function () {
            alert(notes_name.text());
        }
    });
}
```

in the reciever end I have the following:

```
<?php 
    $test = $_GET['nameNotes'];
    echo $test;
?>
```

Nothing happens here though. It goes through but I am unable to get the value of the GET sent? I don't know where its being sent is being opened by JQuery UI dialog box or not. Help needed.

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools?

Comment: In Chrome I get two GETS one that just says GET - ok, the second saying GET and the param is `nameNotes=%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09BillCosby%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09`

Comment: No Idea why all those 0 and stuff are there?

Comment: in between all those 0%A is BillCosby - that is the param I sent.

Comment: Those are URL-encoded newlines & tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your success callback:

```
success: function () {
    alert(notes_name.text());
}
```

you are not retrieving the data from the request. From the jQuery documentation:

> Type: Function( Object data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR ) A
>   function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets
>   passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted
>   according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status;

You should use:

```
success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

Comment: This is not an awnser?  That I don't care about I just wanted to make sure it was sending the right param and it was.

Comment: And you actually have to put .text() because in the firstplace it is a Jquery object.

Comment: @DavidBiga, "It goes through but I am unable to get the value of the GET sent". This *answer* tells you why and how to solve that problem.

Comment: ?  It doesnt matter if I change it or not still nothing on the other end.

Comment: @DavidBiga, also you are returning a string, not a javascript object.

Comment: On the other file displayed above?

Comment: I am not returning anything I was just seeing to see if it was sending a value and it was.

Comment: All I want to do is send something to that file so I can begin PDO'ing.  I don't want to return anything.

Comment: @DavidBiga, you are not even listening to what I say. Your code is incorrect and I posted the fix. I have nothing else to add. Have a nice day.

Comment: sorry man I thought you were talking about what you were saying.  It worked thanks :)

Comment: quick question though,  how come I don't see if once JQuery UI opens?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24252/discussion-between-jeffrey-and-david-biga)